# Bash script, output folder content and bytesize without using ls

Tags: linux, bash, variables, output

I am working on a bash script.
This script should display the content of a folder and his byte size.
Normaly I would use the ls command but in this excercise I can't use it.
The output on the display must be in the format "file_name:bite_size"
So I am trying this for hours an all I get is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=" ";

string="$(du -bc /var/*)";

textArray=($string);

for ((i=0; i<${#textArray[@]}; ++i));
    do
            echo "${textArray[$i]}";
    done
exit 0;
```

I am on the right way or I am totally wrong?

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll note that you shouldn't delete the contents of your original question since that will confuse anyone else who sees this post in the future. Best bet is to simply accept the right answer, as you have already done.

Comment: Ok I am sorry. Tought it would be less confusing. Was there any more possible solution, to make this in a loop without using netstat?

Comment: FYI, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087 is directly on-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
stat --format="%n:%s" *
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you, I try to post the full code.

Comment: +1: This is a great solution for systems with GNU stat. Unfortunately, GNU stat is not a POSIX-standard tool, and not guaranteed to be available everywhere bash runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my first script was that weird. If somebody needs it here's an other solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
echo -n $file:" "
du -b $file | cut -f1
done
```

Comment: This is buggy without more quotes. `du -b "$file"`, or files with names containing spaces won't work. Also, `echo -n` isn't a POSIX-standardized flag; it's better to use `printf` if you want more control over formatting.

Comment: Also, either colon-delimiting or newline-delimiting lists of filenames is a bad idea in the first place, since both colons and newline characters are legitimate within filenames. If you're generating information for machine consumption, rather than human readers, you're better off using NUL delimiters.

Comment: Ok thank you for this information. So how should the full code look with "printf"? I am new to this and I want to learn the correct way.

Comment: Looking at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/du.html, `du -b` isn't a POSIX option, so we'll want to use a different tool. `wc` is probably a better option; modern implementations will use `stat()` under the hood if given an input that points to a file rather than a pipeline, so it doesn't lose efficiency.

Comment: ...so, that might look like this: `for file in *; do echo "${file}: $(wc -c "$file")"; done`, if you wanted to use echo (no `-E` or `-n` needed this way).

Comment: ...or, with printf, it might look like: `for file in *; do printf '%q: %s' "$file" "$(wc -c "$file")"; done`. The use of `%q` is a bash extension -- not in the baseline POSIX printf -- and quotes the filenames for shell input; that means that newlines inside the names will be changed to `$'\n'`, and nonprintable characters will similarly be made printable, making it easier to read the results for unusual names. If you wanted to be compatible with POSIX sh, you'd give up that functionality by changing the %q to a %s.